# What does this Eclipse error mean about my Android app?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse to write my Android app and I keep getting this error when running it. I have no idea what the error means or how to go about debugging.

I should add that this all started when I wrote a method to parse an XML file.  Before I wrote that, the app worked fine.  I tried adding some try/catch block that contain "log.e" statements, but I don't see anything strange in the log.

Does anyone have any idea?

The error message is in the screen shot below:

[image: a error screen]

Comment: I don't know what ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord is...there is nothing like that in my app source code.  When I click on "Edit Source Lookup Path" it takes me to 'default', which looks to be the top-level folder of all my app projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this error come up before for a lot of reasons. Almost always it is because I tried to refer to a resource that either is not there, or is incorrectly formatted. Seeing as how this started when you worked with one of your XML files I would check there for incorrect formatting.

Although this error is referring to the fact that you do not have the full android source code, having it will not fix the error, it will only allow you to see where the source code is failing either to find or open your XML file.

Answer (score 2):

It means you don't have the source files of the Android code in you eclipse workspace. check
[Android source](http://source.android.com/)

By default you only have the compiled class files in you android.jar. if you want to see the source(*.java files) you need to add them yourself. So, you have no source files at all by default

Comment: How would you figure out which source file is missing?  Why are they missing in the first place?

Comment: By default you only have the compiled class files in you android.jar. if you want to see the source(*.java files) you need to add them yourself. So, you have no source files at all by default

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by I don't have the source files...because I do have the source files.  This all started when I wrote a method to process an XML file.

Comment: @999cm999 You have the source files of your own written code, but the screenshot is from the ActivityThread class, which is part of Android

Comment: Do you also have a stacktrace of the exception?